# Why is there a random question mark in my terminal?

Tags: terminal, macos

[image: My terminal]

Hi everyone, I followed this guide: https://gist.github.com/kevin-smets/8568070

I decided not to use the source code pro font as it messed up my terminal with the characters, this one works, but it is displaying a random question mark, then a 5? This is a newly created Rust directory through CLion, with no version control. (I guess CLion just adds an empty git folder?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question mark appears to be a symbol provided by git status and added to your shell prompt.  See [this comment in the tutorial](https://gist.github.com/kevin-smets/8568070?permalink_comment_id=4017920#gistcomment-4017920) for explanations of the punctuation symbols.

Comment: Seems to be it. Thanks!